# On 1-iso maps and subsets of the unit circle

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis

Let $S$ be the unit circle and for any $x,y \in S$ let $d(x,y)$ be the lenght of the smallest arc between $x$ and $y$. A **bijective** map $\phi : S\longrightarrow S$ is called 1-iso if the following holds: 
$$ \forall x,y \in S \;\;  d(x,y)=1 \longleftrightarrow d(\phi (x), \phi (y) ) =1$$
Now the question: Is there a subset $D$ of $S$ such that the only 1-iso map $\phi$ with the property that $\phi (D) = D$ and $\phi (S-D) = S-D$ is the identiry map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any point $a\in S$, there is an infinite (in both directions) chain $\dots,a_{-1},a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots$ of points such that $d(a_i,a_{i+1})=1$, and no other points are at distance $1$ from the points of this chain. The whole circle is partitioned into (continuum of) such chains; for every chain we choose its representative $a_0$.

Now find a bijection between the set of all chains and the set of all infinite strictly increasing sequences $(n_1,n_2,\dots)$ of positive integers. If a coset with representative $a_0$ corresponds to a sequence $(n_1,n_2,\dots)$, we put into $D$ the elements $a_0,a_{n_1},a_{n_1+n_2},\dots$. Perform this operation for all chains.

Now, if $\phi$ is 1-iso and $\phi(D)=D$, then $\phi$ maps $\{a_0,a_{n_1},a_{n_1+n_2},\dots\}$ to either $\{b_i,b_{i+n_1},b_{i+n_1+n_2},\dots\}$ or $\{b_i,b_{i-n_1},b_{i-n_1-n_2},\dots\}$, and this image should equal to $D\cap (\dots,b_{-1},b_0,b_1,\dots\}$. The second set cannot lie in $D$, while the first may equal $D\cap (\dots,b_{-1},b_0,b_1,\dots\}$ only if $b_0=a_0$. Thus $\phi$ is the identity map.

Comment: Thanks, but would you please explain your first line, I am so far from algebra

Comment: I've rephrased the answer; but I should mention that it is quite useful to understand algebraic language on this level.